# Como adicionar a minha validação no Validator do Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

No `Laravel`, tanto o 4 como o 5, temos a classe `Validator`, que permite fazer validações específicas.

Por padrão exista várias, como `required`, `email`, `same` e outros.

Porém eu gostaria também de poder validar um **número de telefone** com **ddd**.

Exemplo:

```
 $valores = ['telefone' => '(31)9995-5088'];

 $rules = ['telefone' => 'required|minha_validacao_de_telefone']

 Validator::make($valores, $regras);
```

Como eu poderia fazer para adicionar uma validação de telefone no `Laravel`?

Existe alguma maneira de adicionar uma expressão regular na validação do `Laravel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, no `Laravel` é possível adicionar a sua própria validação.

No `Laravel 4`, basta adicionar o seguinte código no arquivo `app/start/global.php`:

```
Validator::extend('telefone-com-ddd', function ($attributes, $value) {

    return preg_match('/^\(\d{2}\)\d{4,5}-\d{4}$/', $value) > 0;
});
```

Para utilizar, você pode fazer assim:

```
 Validator::make($valores, ['telefone' => 'required|telefone-com-ddd']);
```

No `Laravel 5`, você tem que criar um `ServiceProvider` referente ao seu   `Validator`  costumizado:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ValidatorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app['validator']->extend('telefone', function ($attribute, $value)
        {
             return preg_match('/^\(\d{2}\)\d{4,5}-\d{4}$/', $value) > 0; 
        });
    }

    public function register(){}
}
```

Depois disso, é necessário adicionar o nome dessa classe no `config/app.php`

```
'providers' => [
    // Other Service Providers

    \App\Providers\ValidatorServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Comment: `^\(\d{2}\) ?\d{4,5}-\d{4}$` :D

Comment: Thanks, manolo!